# Проблема записи распознанного текста с изображения в список

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, динамические-массивы

Всем привет, я новичок в Python, каждое изображение я разрезала на строчки line[i] и поместила в папки photo[j], где j - это номер изображения. То есть в каждой папке photo1, photo2 и тд лежат соответствующие картинки строчек. По данному коду я распознаю текст каждой линии и записываю список, и что-то мне кажется из-за того, что они просто записываются туда сплошником, в дальнейшем проблемы чтения... Так вот как мне записать так, чтобы я могла потом обращаться к списку так results_text[j][i], где j - номер картинки, i соответствующие ей линии? Большое спасибо заранее, если вы попытаетесь помочь!

'''

```
    for j in range(constants.num):
        for i in range(constants.string):
            img = cv2.cv2.imread("temp/photo%s/line%s.jpg" % (j,i)) # Чтение заданного изображения.
            img_grey = cv2.cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Перевод изображения в черно-белый формат.
            message = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_grey) # Распознавание текста.
            results_text.append(message) # Запись результата в список.
```

'''

Comment: ничего не понятно. Какие у изображений строчки, да еще и с текстом?

Comment: @Эникейщик файлы формата jpg, на которых изображен цветной текст на черном фоне, со считыванием строчек нет проблем, интересует именно как записать каждую строчку с каждого изображения в двумерный список, чтобы  например элемент списка с индексом [j][i] соответствовал j-ому изображению, i-ой строчке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать чтобы `results_text` был двумерным массивом (т.е. списком списков):

```
results_text = []
for j in range(constants.num):
    results_text.append([]) # новая строка которая будет содержать список для строк
    # results_text[j] содержит список, в который будем добавлять резйльтаты для строк по порядку
    for i in range(constants.string):
        img = cv2.cv2.imread("temp/photo%s/line%s.jpg" % (j,i)) # Чтение заданного изображения.
        img_grey = cv2.cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Перевод изображения в черно-белый формат.
        message = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_grey) # Распознавание текста.
        results_text[j].append(message) # Запись результата в список.
        # теперь results_text[j][i] содержит результат для j-го photo и i-ой линии
```

Comment: просто огромнейшее вам спасибо!!!) А то я не понимала как в двумерный записывать и информацию не смогла найти